# How to completely delete Bitnami WAMP server?

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp, bitnami, ampps

I installed Bitnami WAMP and I tried to uninstall it and use AMPPS instead of Bitnami WAMP. 
I deleted Bitnami WAMP but it wasn't deleted completely. 
I can still find WMAP files in 'Setting > Service' : 'wampstack Apache' and 'wampstack MySQL' files are still there. 
 
And, When I run AMPPS, I can't run Apache and PHP 7.1.
An error message occurs and it says "Apache port:80 is being used by another application"

fyi, This is how I uninstall Bitnami WAMP : 
1. Run Bitnami uninstall file 
2. Remove Bitnami folder 
 - Even after running that file, Bitnami folder still remained, so I remove that folder by GitBash.
 - `rm -r -f Bitnami` 

How Can I remove Bitnami WAMP perfectly? 
I searched google a lot but couldn't find how to do. ;( 
I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the PID of the Apache and Mysql processes using netstat:

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep apache
```

and

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep mysql
```

And then stop them:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

After stopping the processes it should be possible to remove the folder.

Comment: Thank you for your help! : )